# Entity Framework Group Join on a Many To Many Relationship

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I have a Campaign Table and a Group table with a many to many relationship.  I also have a CampaignGroup table which serves the xref table between the two.

I want to do a group join from Campaign to Group so that I end up with an object that looks like:

```
public Campaign Campaign {get;set;}
public List<Group> Groups {get;set;}
```

Due to reasons beyond my control, I cannot use Entity Framework's Include feature.

If I can do a Group Join from Campaign to CampaignGroup like this:

```
_dbContext.Campaigns.GroupJoin(_dbContext.CampginGroup,
c => c.CampaignId,
cg => cg.CampaignId,
(c, cg) => new 
{
    Campaign = c,
    CampaignGroups = cg
}
```

But that gives me an object that looks like:

```
public Campaign Campaign {get;set;}
public List<CampaignGroup> CampaignGroups {get;set;}
```

How do I take this GroupJoin to the next level and get just the group?

I tried this, but when it executes Entity Framework warns me that it can't be evaluated and will be performed locally which kills the performance:

```
        var campaignGroupQuery = _dbContext.CampaignGroup.Join(
            _dbContext.Group,
            cg=> cg.GroupId,
            g=> g.GroupId,
            (cg, g) => new
            {
                CampaignId = cg.CampaignId,
                Group= g
            });

        return _dbContext.Campaigns.GroupJoin(campaignGroupQuery,
            campaign => campaign.JlmReferenceId,
            cg=> cg.JlmReferenceId,
            (campaign, cg) => new 
            {
                Campaign = campaign,
                Groups = cg.Select(cg => cg.Group)
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the relationship Campaign CampaignGroup Group and Group ? 1-many -1 which is making the many to many?

Comment: Also not being able to use Include seems to be a serious limitation, i mean this is seriously going to limit any future efforts and efficiency in lots of places and situations. whats the reasons behind this?

Comment: Campaign has a many to many relationship with Group. CampaignGroup has a CampaignId and a GroupId field.

Comment: Ahh ok just a standard mapping table.

Comment: Yep. You are correct.